# Can we apply the Probability Integral Transform to Dependent Random Variables?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, poisson-process, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Let's suppose we deal with a non-homogeneous Poisson process having intensity function `λ(t), t ≥ 0`. The event times `X1, X2, …` of such a process are dependent random variables, described by a conditional distribution.
I need to apply the (empirical) probability integral transformation in order to run Goodness-of-Fit tests (test of homogeneity).
Can we apply the (empirical) probability integral transformation to `X1, X2, …`? As far as I know, this transformation can be applied to i.i.d. observations on `X`. However, in this case, we deal with event times that depend on event times of other events.

Comment: Check the `copula` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use the conditional predictive distribution $F_t$ at each time point $t$ and plug in the actual observation $X_t$. (As an example, I did so in the context of density forecasting for retail sales in [Kolassa, 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.004).)

Note that a uniform histogram resulting from the PIT is necessary, but not sufficient, to deduce that your densities are calibrated ([Gneiting et al., 2007)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00587.x)).

Comment: Thank you Stephan. However, I cannot use the explicit formulation of the conditional intensity describing the non-homogeneous Poisson process. I can only use the empirical CDF.